# Отображение даты в JDatePicker

Tags: java, swing

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно сделать так, что бы в окне JDataPicker по умолчанию отображалась текущая дата?

```
public class WordWorker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        UtilDateModel model=new UtilDateModel();

        Properties p=new Properties();
        p.put("text.today","Today");
        p.put("text.month","Month");
        p.put("text.year","Year");
        JDatePanelImpl datePanel=new JDatePanelImpl(model,p);
        DateFormatter dateFormatter=new DateFormatter();

        JDatePickerImpl datePicker=new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel,dateFormatter);

        datePicker.setTextEditable(true);

        frame.add(datePicker,"Center");
        JButton jButton=new JButton("Кнопка");
        jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(datePicker.getModel().getDay());
                System.out.println(datePicker.getModel().getMonth()+1);
                System.out.println(datePicker.getModel().getYear());
                System.out.println(datePicker.getModel().getValue());
            }
        });

        frame.add(jButton,"South");
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }
    public static class DateFormatter extends JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter {

        private String datePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
        private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);

        @Override
        public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(dateFormatter.parse(text));
            return cal;
        }

        @Override
        public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
            if (value != null) {
                Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
                return dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
            }

            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
 // Модель даты
 UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();

 // Инициализация значения
 model.setDate(new Date());

 // Отображение в текстовом поле
 model.setSelected(true);
```